# In what scenario , the No-VPC option available while creating a DB-Instance Through Amazon RDS. Under Network and Security Option

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-vpc, amazon-rds

[This is the available VPC Drop Down Options.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3Ql5P.png)

According to AWS Documentation, There are 3 kind of vpc

*1. Default-VPC

2. User Defined VPC
3. NO-VPC*

**What are the all possible scenarios where we can get No-VPC in Drop Down.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No VPC option is available in EC2 classic accounts  - ie., the accounts that were created few years back when VPC was an option. It is no longer the case now. All new accounts have to choose a VPC. If no VPC option does not appear for you, then you have only 2 options: Default and User Defined.